# Objective-c Passing Parameters into IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing for real-time audio processing on iPhone SDK, I used the 'EZAudio' to get the data from microphone and then filter them with a high pass filter, and finally plot them with the help of 'EZAudio'.

I set two buttons to plot original waveform and filtered waveform. I don't know how to pass the data from microphone to the -(IBAction)?

Here is my code:

Data from `microphoneDelegate`

```
-(void)    microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
     hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer
       withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
 withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Update time domain plot
    [self.audioPlotTime updateBuffer:buffer[0]
                      withBufferSize:bufferSize];

    });
}
```

The high pass filter I have written:

```
-(void)processSampleForHighOrLowPassFilter:(float)bufferSize
                             withAudioData:(float*)inBuffer
                            withFilterType:(UInt32)filterType {

    float *outBuffer = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*bufferSize);

    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++) {

        outBuffer[i] = (a0 * (inBuffer[i])) 
                       + (a1 * tmpBufferInIndex[0])
                       + (a2 * tmpBufferInIndex[1])
                       - (b1 * tmpBufferOutIndex[0]) 
                       - (b2 * tmpBufferOutIndex[1]);

        tmpBufferInIndex[1] = tmpBufferInIndex[0];
        tmpBufferInIndex[0] = inBuffer[i];
        tmpBufferOutIndex[1] = tmpBufferOutIndex[0];
        tmpBufferOutIndex[0] = outBuffer[i];
   }

   [self.audioPlotHighPassFilter8kHz updateBuffer:outBuffer
                                    withBufferSize:bufferSize];
}
```

I want to use a button to trigger ploting the original waveform and the waveform after processing

```
-(void)plotOriginalWaveForm:(id)sender {
    //[self.audioPlot updateBuffer:outBuffer
    //              withBufferSize:bufferSize];
}

-(void)plot8kHzWaveForm:(id)sender {
    //[self.audioPlotHighPassFilter8kHz updateBuffer:outBuffer
    //                                withBufferSize:bufferSize];
}
```

But I don't understand how to pass the `buffer` and `bufferSize` into the IBAction,  because I will call the plot function in it and the plot function needs these two parameters.

Thank you if you would give some advice or are there any other ways to use the data from microphone in the IBAction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store the buffer and buffersize information as a property on your class, set them when you get called in your microphone delegate, and retrieve them from the property when you plot the waveforms, rather than passing around as parameters.

Edit to give possible example, depending on the classes that were around your original code:

in your .h file in the @interface block:

```
{
    float ** myBuffer;
    UInt32 myBufferSize;
}
```

In your methods:

```
-(void)    microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
     hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer
       withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
 withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {

    self.myBuffer = buffer;
    self.myBufferSize = bufferSize;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Update time domain plot
    [self.audioPlotTime updateBuffer:buffer[0]
                  withBufferSize:bufferSize];

     });
}

-(void)plotOriginalWaveForm:(id)sender {
    [self.audioPlot myBuffer
                  myBufferSize];
}

-(void)plot8kHzWaveForm:(id)sender {
    [self.audioPlotHighPassFilter8kHz myBuffer
                                withBufferSize:myBufferSize];
}
```

Comment: I am a new comer to objective-c, if you would provide some code as explanation, it would be a great help for me! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does works! But it occurs another problem that the data are fixed when I click the button, not real-time. I will  think it over how to deal with it.